# Assign half of cores to a docker container in swarm mode

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I want to limit a service to half the processing power of the machine it is hosted in.

If I have a machine with 8 cores, `--cpus` should be set to `4.0`, but if I have only 4, it should be `2.0`.

Is it possible to do this using just a `docker-compose.yml` file?

Comment: The best way to do this would be to just make the web app single threaded and stateless, and then deploy many replicas. Docker swarm should place more replicas on nodes with more available resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple script to get this information and inject it into compose. This will not work for swarm mode:

```bash
CPUS="$(($(grep -c "processor" /proc/cpuinfo)/2))" docker-compose up -d
```

and then use the variable in compose:

```yaml
services:
  frontend:
    image: awesome/webapp
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: ${CPUS}
          memory: 50M
          pids: 1
```

Explanaition of the bash command:
`/proc/cpuinfo` contains information about every core in the system. Searching for "processor" yields one match per core. `-c` flag returns the number of matches instead of the matched lines. `$()` runs the command in a subshell, so `$(grep -c "processor" /proc/cpuinfo)` will evaluate to let's say 4. `$(())` can do simple calculation in bash so we divide the found cores by two and get our result. One caveat is that this only works with core counts divisible by 2, because it only does integer arithmetic.

Comment: But this wouldn't work with docker stack, as the env value would be the same for all nodes

Comment: Correct. I am afraid you can't achieve this with docker swarm. What you can try (but I wouldn't recommend it) is to give your container access to the systemd managed cgroups and adjust the values for the container cgroup itself. This approach is a high security risk. You probably could come up with something, if you were using kubernetes, but even with kubernetes it wouldn't be easy.

Comment: And is it possible using docker swarm to set the cpu shares of the service?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was mistaken. There is a way to set half of the CPU. It is just not in the usual place, so I missed it. Looking again at the [compose file specification](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#cpu_percent) there is an attribute making this possible. I haven't used this myself so I am not sure if this works with swarm mode, but according to the documentation it should work like this:

```yaml
services:
  frontend:
    image: awesome/webapp
    cpu_percent: 50
```

You can also find that there is a `cpu_shares` attribute that could be useful.